# Challenge Mat adapter?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I bought a new Wii, and the Challenge Mat I had with my old Wii does not attach to my new Wii system. Is there an adapter for it?

Comment: Where are you trying to connect it? the connections should be the same from a Wii to an other.

Answer (score 1):

I think this mat plug in the gamecube port of the Wii, no adapter needed.

Just plug the mat where this gamecube controller is plugged.

[image]

Comment: I can't hook my mat up to my new wii either. The plug does not fit. The wii pictured is an old wii system not the new one. The new one doesn't flip open nor does it have a stand. I don't know if there's an adapter of some sort. If I find one I'll update my comment.

Comment: Some Wiis are now being made without GameCube support, which I suspect is the problem here.